# PouchDb fetch all documents by Id matching regex

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I would like to get all documents with id matching a regex expression.

For example I have the following doc ids:

```
p0
p0/e0
p1
p1/e0
```

How can I get only p0 and p1 ? Regex would be /^p[0-9]+$/

Currently I can do it performing two requests, but I would like to use only one:

```
This.db.allDocs({
    include_docs: false
}).then(function(result){

    // Find all ids matching /^p[0-9]+$/
    var iDoc = result.rows.length;
    while(iDoc--){
        if(result.rows[iDoc].id.match(/^p[0-9]+$/)){
            projectsIds.push(result.rows[iDoc].id);
        }
    }

    // Get all documents with ids matching /^p[0-9]+$/
    This.db.allDocs({
        include_docs: true,
        keys: projectsIds
    }).then(function(result) {
        var iProject = result.rows.length;
        var docs = [];
        while (iProject--) {
            docs[iProject] = result.rows[iProject].doc;
        }
        projects.resolve(docs);

    });

});
```

Comment: what kind of regular expression you use?can  you provide more information on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch all your docs using `allDocs()` and then filter in memory using JavaScript.

This requires reading your entire database into memory, but PouchDB cannot index on a regex, so it's what you have to do! Else you can design your IDs so that it's easier to do prefix searching as described by the other commenter.

Comment: Okay thanks, so it's exactly what I'm doing right now. Do I have to validate this kind of answer which is good but doesn't solve my problem ?

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that it doesn't solve your problem. In reality, most databases do not allow you to index on regular expressions, so in fact when you do "regex" searches (or `LIKE` queries in SQL), in fact what is going on is that the database is doing a full table scan and then returning the results, which you can do yourself with equally bad performance. :) The only database I'm aware of that can index on such "fuzzy" queries is Lucene/Solr: http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html

Answer (score 6):

this possible to get document by prefix, for
example

```
localDB.allDocs({
            include_docs: true,
            startkey: "p0",
            endkey: "p0\uffff"
        },...);
```

above code gives you all document which _id is start with p0.

refer link
https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-quick-search#autosuggestions-and-prefix-search

Comment: This code will get "p0" and "p0/e0", this is not what I want.

Comment: You can go for filter function and in that you can define your logic

Comment: I know filter feature for replication, but how to use it to retrieve docs ? May I need to get all my docs ids with include_docs: false, apply my filter on result, and then perform a second request with keys match option ?

Comment: You can use allDocs function with keys option which accept array of string to fetch specified docs in single shot.

Comment: I mean matching this regex exactly: /^p[0-9]+$/

Answer (score 1):

A few years later and it looks like `pouchdb-find` plugin might have helped (written by @nlawson above, i think). Here's the Pouch docs talking about querying with it... https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_index

And how you'd do it:

```
async test()
  let result = await This.db.find({
    selector: {_id: {$regex: '^p[0-9]+$'}}
  });
  let docs = result.rows.map( row => row.doc )
  console.dir(docs)
}
```

(i made it async just so you don't have to faff about with callbacks)

You can try it out for yourself on pouchdb-find plugin's [site](http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/).

Performance may be terrible though, I've not tried it. @nlawson seems to think a regex on an index can't be done quickly and he surely knows better than most.

*EDIT: I just checked the Pouch docs mentioned above and indexes are definitely used during the find process, so performance might be ok.*